# JSON syntax not working. What is my error?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

i have this command line.

```
for i in ${admin_users[@]}; do aws ssm send-command --document-name "---" --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=$instance_id" --parameters {"username":["$i"]} --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region us-east-1 --query 'Command.CommandId'; sleep 5; done
```

just for references sake here is the adminusers value

```
admin_users=( value.1 value.2 value.3 )
```

i get this error

```
Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:
```

I have the value enclosed in double quotes which is why i am confused. Any ideas as to what my error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap parameters JSON value in single quotes as shown in the below example from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/monitoring-sns-rc-send.html). By doing this it can read this as a string (before it is parsed as JSON).

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "ID-1, ID-2" --document-name "Name" --parameters '{"commands":["input"]}' --service-role "SNSRoleARN" --notification-config '{"NotificationArn":"SNSTopicName","NotificationEvents":["All"],"NotificationType":"Command"}'
```